# Is there a way to configure South to migrate without asking any questions?

Tags: django, django-south

I'm using Django South for managing my database schema updates. As I'm currently developing locally, my models are changing a lot, and it's really annoying to change things with South:

```
$ bin/django schemamigration --auto core
(Please provide a default value for new field...)
...
$ bin/django migrate core
```

It often takes forever to do simple things like add and remove columns from the database, as South prompts me to provide default values even for columns I'm deleting.

Is there a setting that will cause South to work much more like Hibernates `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` setting and automatically, promptlessly, awesomely update my database schema without any fuss? Is there an alternative library for doing this?

South is really important to me for deployment migrations, but I need something to help me change things fast as I'm rapidly prototyping things.

Comment: Have you try with `--no-input` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/index.html) to help with local and production changes. This is a function in my fabfile.py. It helps with any changes I want to make.

```
def run_local():
"""
Installs requirements, syncs the database, migrates with south, and runs the server.
"""
local('pip install -r conf/requirements.txt')
local('python manage.py syncdb')
local('python manage.py migrate')
local('python manage.py runserver')
```